# Use pipe on bindLabel at <ng-select>

Tags: angular, pipe

```
<ng-select 
    [items]="prozessItem$ | async" 
    [multiple]="true" 
    bindLabel="itemName | umlautsPipe" 
    bindValue="nrItems"
></ng-select>
```

I want to pipe the itemName from `"üäößTEST"` to `"ueaeoessTest"`. The async pipe works just fine and without the pipe I get `"üäößTEST"`. Ng-select only accepts a string value in the attribute. I may be misunderstanding it but I believe that when I use `bindLabel="itemName | umlautsPipe"`, ng-select is attempting to reference `item[itemName | umlautsPipe]` which does not exist.

So how can I transform the name of the item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you have to use a template, try:

```
<ng-select 
    [items]="prozessItem$ | async" 
    [multiple]="true" 
    bindValue="nrItems"
>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
      {{ item.itemName | umlautsPipe }}
   </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: please consider adding ng-label-tmp to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @AliF50

but need to use the combination of **ng-option-tmp ng-label-tmp** if you need to.

```
<ng-select 
    [items]="prozessItem$ | async" 
    [multiple]="true" 
    bindValue="nrItems"
>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
      {{ item.itemName | umlautsPipe }}
   </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Thank you! this answer is complete as ng-label-tmp is important to display the selected value correctly.

Answer (score -1):

use `[bindLabel]="name"` instead of `bindLabel="name"`. If you use brackets the value name is interpolated.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem of accessing item, to preform item.itemName | pipe